# How to set up retry failures link in jenkins with different maven command for cucumber java automation

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to set up retry failure link in jenkins. This is for cucumber selenium automation. Please answer below questions:

1) How can we set up retry link in jenkins with different maven command?

2) How to make it automatically run retry after normal build run?

Comment: any one please help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How rerun failed test cases of cucumber-jvm in jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59364351/how-rerun-failed-test-cases-of-cucumber-jvm-in-jenkins)